# debugging c++ : ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm using `gdb` to debug a `C++` program. In the line

```
assert(prevId ==  GetTagIdFromState(maxState));
```

- the parameter `prevId` value is `0`;
- the method `GetTagIdFromState(maxState)` `return`s `50`;

when debugging this, I get the following errors.

```
Assertion `prevId == GetTagIdFromState(maxState)' failed.
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff6ecbba5 in raise (sig=<value optimized out>) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
64    ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
      in ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c
```

Comment: If anyone stumbled upon this, I had the same error. What cleared it up for my was there was a lock that was locked, but never released. I'm not sure why it didn't just deadlock. Don't know if that'll help, but figured I'd pass on my gotcha.

Answer (score 10):

Your application works as intended. The assertion fails (since the values you pass to it are not equal, the `assert` macro receives 0), and thus your program is being aborted. That's how asserts work:

> If NDEBUG is not defined, then **assert checks if its argument** (which
>   must have scalar type) **compares equal to zero. If it does, assert
>   outputs implementation-specific diagnostic information on the standard
>   error output and calls std::abort**.

emphasis mine.

Check [this assert reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) for further information.

Comment: Thank you first. I am new to C++. I knew that the assertion fails, but can you give me some advice why the error "../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory." araises. It seems that the program can not found the file.

Comment: It's nothing to worry about. The assert macro is calling (probably indirectly) a function called raise. This is happening inside a library that you are linking with your code. When that library was compiled (on some other machine) there was a file called '../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c', but now when it's running on your machine that file no longer exists. If you want to make this error go away then you probably have to download the source code for this library.

Comment: @wangzhiju, well, judging from the path, it looks like the lib you are using was compiled on it's developer's machine with using a file `../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c`. Since there is no such file on your machine, you have the error. It shouldn't lead to any problems though so you might as well ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this error while trying to debug a program on a Raspberry Pi.  The program happens to use the GPIO in a manner that requires that the program be run as root.  For example, I run the program I wrote like this:

```
sudo ./foo
```

I forgot this, however, when starting up the debugger, and tried

```
gdb foo
```

And I got the error you seem to have encountered:

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x76cd0f70 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

When I ran it using sudo, it worked fine.

```
sudo gdb foo
```

Hope that's helpful to someone in the same boat.

Comment: @code_dragon, my program need to run as root, and hit an assertion when it wasn't running as such.  The assertion you hit is probably caused by some other error condition you encountered.  The error in this question means an assertion was hit.  In my case, the assertion was satisfied by running the program as root.

Comment: @Neppomuk, I posted it as help for someone else hitting the same issue.  We're all learning here.

Answer (score 0):

This should bring you up to speed about using assert function

```
void assert (int expression);
```

Evaluate assertion
If the argument expression of this macro with functional form compares equal to zero (i.e., the expression is false), a message is written to the standard error device and abort is called, terminating the program execution.

The specifics of the message shown depend on the specific implementation in the compiler, but it shall include: the expression whose assertion failed, the name of the source file, and the line number where it happened. A usual expression format is:

Assertion failed: expression, file filename, line line number
This macro is disabled if at the moment of including assert.h a macro with the name NDEBUG has already been defined. This allows for a coder to include many assert calls in a source code while debugging the program and then disable all of them for the production version by simply including a line like:

```
#define NDEBUG at the beginning of its code, before the inclusion of assert.h.
```

Therefore, this macro is designed to capture programming errors, not user or running errors, since it is generally disabled after a program exits its debugging phase.
from: [C++ Ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cassert/assert/)